# python mock side_effect or return_value dependent on call_count

Tags: python, mocking

To test a polling function I want to mock the calling of a sub function so that the first time it is called it will fail, and the second time it is called it will succeed. Here's a very simplified version of it:

```
poll_function(var1):
    value = sub_function(var1)  # First call will return None
    while not value:
        time.sleep(POLLING_INTERVAL)  
        value = sub_function(var1) # A subsequent call will return a string, e.g "data"
    return value
```

Is this possible to do with a `Mock` object from the `mock` framework? I know `Mock` objects have a `call_count` attribute I should be able to use somehow.

Right now I've solved it by creating a custom mock object that I use to monkey patch `sub_function()`, but I feel there should be a better less verbose way of doing it:

```
def test_poll():
    class MyMock(object):                                                      

        def __init__(self, *args):                                             
            self.call_count = 0                                                

        def sub_function(self, *args, **kwargs):                             
            if self.call_count > 1:                                            
                return "data"            
            else:                                                              
                self.call_count += 1                                           
                return None  

    my_mock = MyMock()                                                         
    with patch('sub_function', my_mock.sub_function):           
        ok_(poll_function())
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do it by [setting `side_effect` to an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).  For your simple case:

```
>>> mock_poll = Mock(side_effect=[None, 'data'])
>>> mock_poll()
None
>>> mock_poll()
'data'
```

If you want to allow for an unlimited number of calls, use the `itertools` `cycle` and `chain` functions:

```
>>> mock_poll = Mock(side_effect=chain(['first'], cycle(['others'])))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this worked quite well. Worth to note, however, is that this _doesn't_ work on `mock` version `0.7.2`, which is what I was on at the time. I had to upgrade to version `0.8.0` to use this feature properly.